# Firestore security rules - allow if user creates his account using phone number

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I want firebase security rules to allow if user creates his account using phone number.
I try to using

`request.auth.token.phone_number`

But not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing it wrong correct syntax will be:

```
request.auth.token.firebase.sign_in_provider == "phone";
```